# How to make Bootstrap dropdown button to display the first value from dropdown menu?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, model-view-controller, drop-down-menu

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="form-group">
 <label for="Environment">Environment</label>
   <div class="dropdown">
     <button class="dropdown-toggle form-control btn-sm" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true">
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Environment)
        <span id="displaytext"> @Model.GetEnvironments().First()</span>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down pull-right"></span>
     </button>
     <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
          @foreach (string product in Model.GetEnvironments())
          {
            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1">@product</a></li>
          }
     </ul>
   </div>
</div>
```

This is a very inefficient code as I am calling `GetEnvironments()` twice.

Basically I want the user to compulsorily select a value before submitting the form. I don't want to use *select* as I would lose all my css styling and modifying *select* is quite cumbersome. If I cannot make the button (here `span` with `id="displaytext"`) to display the first element, I should be able to make it a required field at least.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call `GetEnvironments` just once you can do it by storring first call in a variable, this way will be more efficient.

```
@{ 
    var environments = @Model.GetEnvironments(); // store data
}
<div class="form-group">
 <label for="Environment">Environment</label>
   <div class="dropdown">
     <button class="dropdown-toggle form-control btn-sm" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true">
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Environment)
        <span id="displaytext"> @environments.First()</span>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down pull-right"></span>
     </button>
     <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
          @foreach (string product in environments)
          {
            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1">@product</a></li>
          }
     </ul>
   </div>
</div>
```